# TRYING TO USE javascript to manipulate the DOM css

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

im trying to manipulate the DOM using JavaScript and im trying to change the css color and background-color using JavaScript

```js
const container=document.body
container.append(`you attaach the append to the body first `)
const div=document.createElement(`div`)
div.style.cssText='color:red; background-color: blue;'
container.append(div)
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. Removed the tag.

Comment: The div is being created with the intended styles, but it has no content.

Comment: "*[I'm] trying to manipulate the DOM using JavaScript and [I'm] trying to change the [CSS] `color` and `background-color` using JavaScript*" - and? What's your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: your code does what you wrote - it's hard to see with an empty div that it indeed does have red text on a blue background - try adding `div.textContent = 'oh my gosh it works';` to your code

Comment: Or, alternatively, set that style on the container: `container.style.cssText = 'color:red; background-color: blue;';`. Depends on what your use-case is.

Comment: You probably want `div.append(document.createTextNode(\`you attaach the append to the body first \`))` ...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you can't get but i think you did not get the css style to work so this is the answer i guess if that what you are stuck on

```js
const container = document.body;
const div = document.createElement(`div`);
div.textContent = 'you attach the append to the body first.';
div.style.cssText = 'color: red; background-color: blue;';

container.append(div);
```

```html
<body></body>
```